# member function constraint madness

Tags: f#, type-constraints

I should probably go to sleep... but all it takes is to make this dang member constraint to be accepted...

I think I applied the member function constraints correctly and in abundance and still I get:

> error FS0072: Lookup on object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed prior to this program point to constrain the type of the object. This may allow the lookup to be resolved.

I am even tempted to think that I applied it in too many spots...

```
// ... inside a class type
member public this.ToJSON() =
    let inline arrayToString (arr : ^T [] when ^T : (member ToJSON : unit -> string)) =
        let toString x = x.ToString()
        let len = Array.length arr
        let inline folder (sb : System.Text.StringBuilder,i) (element : ^T when ^T : (member ToJSON : unit -> string)) = 
            sb.Append(element.ToJSON() + if i < len then "," else ""), i+1
//--------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ complains here!
        arr

        |> Array.fold folder (new System.Text.StringBuilder(),1) 
        |> fst
        |> toString
    let inline arrayToString2 (arr : ^T [][] when ^T : (member ToJSON : unit -> string)) =
        let toString x = x.ToString()   
        let len = Array.length arr           
        arr
        |> Array.fold
            ( fun (sb : System.Text.StringBuilder,i) a ->
                sb.Append("[" + (arrayToString a) + if i < len then "]," else "]"),i+1
            ) (new System.Text.StringBuilder(),1) 
        |> fst
        |> toString
    sprintf 
        """{"SymbolTable":[%s],"ProductionTable":[%s],"ParserTables":[%s],"InitialTable":%d,"InitialState":%d}"""
        (arrayToString this.SymbolTable)
        (arrayToString this.ProductionTable)
        (arrayToString2 this.ParserTables)
        (this.InitialTable)
        (this.InitialState)
```

Can anyone tell me how to do it right? The arrayToString is supposed to be generic over the array types contained as members in my class type...

F# 3.1 btw. On .NET (not on mono or something). In VS 2013 Community. Portable Library project.

Thanks, in advance!

**Edit**:

Thanks to ildjarns tip in the comment section, the cryptographically foolproof syntax to get it right looks like this:

```
let inline folder (sb : System.Text.StringBuilder,i) (element : ^T when ^T : (member ToJSON : unit -> string)) = 
    sb.Append((^T : (member ToJSON : unit -> string) element) + if i < len then "," else ""), i+1
```

Comment: So I would have to write that cryptic voodoo declaration for my folder function?

Comment: Yes indeed. :-] Though the declaration is unnecessary, as it is implied; it's the _invocation_ that requires said syntax.

Comment: @ildjarn While it makes no sense to my sleep deprived mind whatsoever, it works! :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can omit `(element : ^T when ^T : (member ToJSON : unit -> string))` in favor of `element`; as I said, the constraint is implied, only your invocation needs changed.